# net/http server freezes under ab (ApacheBench) heavy load

Tags: go, httpserver

Golang `net/http` server on MacOS freezes after 16000 requests:

```
$ ab -c 4 -n 20000 http://127.0.0.1:8080/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1826891 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
...
Completed 14000 requests
Completed 16000 requests
^C
```

Answer (score -2):

Following is the explanation by Bill Neubauer:

> This issue is caused by the OS running out of sockets.  ab and Go are
>   cycling through socket pairs for communication faster than the OS can
>   reallocate them for reuse.

Refer to https://github.com/golang/go/issues/66#issuecomment-66047858